# How do I upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 14.04

What steps do I take to upgrade from LTS 12.04 to LTS 14.04 with the least amount of trouble and loosing the fewest amount of data.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update && sudo do-release-upgrade -d`?

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 with `do-release-upgrade` command
Also check http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04